# Apache, PHP and MySQL portable?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

can I run Apache, PHP and MySQL on a External HD? I need this because I work in diferent 
computers, and sometimes I don't have installed and configured all aplications for use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure thing, [**XAMPP**](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) works well for this. It bundles **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**HP (and **P**erl) and can work on Windows, Solaris, Mac OSX or Linux.

There's a version here that is optimized for portability on your USB device of choice.

[Portable XAMPP](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp)

Answer (score 7):

I have been using the Uniform server for some time now. It has a small footprint and works nicely. http://www.uniformserver.com/

Comment: Note: I've tried it and it requires you to place it in a directory without spaces, such as `C:\UniServer\`. This may or may not offend you.

Answer (score 3):

I want to share with you few portable applications. I recommended `EasyPHP` app.

1. [EasyPHP DevServer](http://www.easyphp.org/)
2. [UwAmp](http://www.uwamp.com/en/)

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use [UsbWebServer](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/):

> USBWebserver is a combination of the popular webserver software: Apache, MySQL, Php and PhpMyAdmin. With USBWebserver it is possible to develop and show your php websites, everywhere and anytime The advantage of USBWebserver is, you can use it from USB of even CD.

Answer (score 1):

I use and would recommend Server2Go you can download a copy of it from http://www.server2go-web.de/