# How to run the equivilant of PHP and MySQL on portable media (eg CD, USB and/or iPhone)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, portability

I use a local installation of Apache, MySQL, and PHP with XAMPP which require a bit of configuration and installation - is there an alternative language or database system that can be used on portable media such as a CD or DVD-Rom? Although this question is similar to [apache-php-and-mysql-portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582861/apache-php-and-mysql-portable) - I'm looking more for the best portable alternative.

Some thoughts I've had so far are:

**Database**: data can be stored in csv, txt files, xml, json or xls and accessed via javascript. This would at least allow for reading of data. Is there a simple way of writing to a installation data directory or at least system temporary location?

**PHP**: Not sure of an alternative but a "server-side" language would help with complex functions.

Otherwise if it's a CD or DVD could part of the installation of the "app" include a PHP/MySQL installation (or equivalent) in a temporary location?

Comment: It would help a bit if you explained your needs in more detail - specifically what you're going to be using this system for?  How much configuration can you rely on the end user to do?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you create a LIVE CD/DVD(media) w/an OS that has the stack you need, all pre-configured?

Answer (score 0):

If you jailbreak an iPhone, you can run many popular *nix tools, including web servers. I'm not sure if PHP is ported yet, but it could easily be.

Not necessarily *on* the iPhone, but you can also use an iPhone as a virtual USB key if you are jailbroken.